# Any way to create a list of dataframes, while retaining dataframe object type?

Tags: r

Is there anyway to create a list of dataframes while keeping the dataframe object type?  The reason I am trying to do this is that I am trying to loop a function over the list of dataframes, and the function only works on objects of class `data.frame`.  For instance:

```
> df<-data.frame("A"=c(1,1,1,1), "B"=c(2,2,2,2), "C"=c(3,3,3,3))
    A B C
  1 1 2 3
  2 1 2 3
  3 1 2 3
  4 1 2 3
> class(df)
    [1] "data.frame"

> lst<-list(df)
> class(lst[1])
    [1] "list"
```

Comment: Well, `data.frame`s and `list`s are two distinct classes. What is the function you are trying to use?

Comment: As nongkrong's last sentence below suggests, you should select elements of lists with `[[`. When you use `[`, you're just selecting a "sublist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
attr(lst, "class") <- "data.frame"
class(lst[1])
[1] "data.frame"
```

but, you probably just want `class(lst[[1]])` to begin with.